# Change mongoose schema viewModel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have problem with related schema in mongoose:
I have 3 Schemas:

```
var recipeProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' },
    productWeight: Number
}, {toJSON: {virtuals: true}});

var recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    products: [RecipeProduct]
})

var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    weight: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
})
```

When I want to create recipe with products I send:

```
{
    "name": "Cake",
    "products": [
        {
            "product": "597a517b7c2e8508c8cc3f3a",
            "productWeight": 50
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I get details about recipe I get this:

```
{
    "_id": "597f7d0ce25d1413149aa30d",
    "name": "Cake",
    "products": [
        {
            "product": {
                "_id": "597a517b7c2e8508c8cc3f3a",
                "name": "Sugar",
                "weight": 400,
                "price": 40
            },
            "productWeight": 50,
            "_id": "597b825a61736b1adcb0ed0f",
            "productPrice": "5.00",
            "id": "597b825a61736b1adcb0ed0f"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to make these two json simmilar to each other?
Because in edit recipe view I don't want to change Recipe's products objects before data send;

I want to send this json:

```
{
    "name": "Cake",
    "products": [
        {
            "product": {
                "id": "597a517b7c2e8508c8cc3f3a" // or "_id"
            },
            "productWeight": 50
        }
    ]
}
```

And I would like to get:

```
{
    "_id": "597f7d0ce25d1413149aa30d",
    "name": "Cake",
    "products": [
        {
            "product": {
                "_id": "597a517b7c2e8508c8cc3f3a",
                "name": "Sugar",
                "weight": 400,
                "price": 40
            },
            "productWeight": 50,
            "_id": "597f7d0ce25d1413149aa30e",
            "productPrice": "5.00",
            "id": "597f7d0ce25d1413149aa30e"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing a children/parent relation

```
var recipeProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    product: [productSchema],
    productWeight: Number
}, {toJSON: {virtuals: true}});

var recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    products: [recipeProductSchema]
})

var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    weight: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
})
```

and do a `$push` into your create function.

also you can use mongoose populate in your get function